# onActivityResult is not updating my current imageView

Tags: java, android

I have searched all over SO answers and tried everything, from `mImageView.postInvalidate()` to doing this

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            filePath = data.getData();

            try {
                mImageView.setImageURI(null);
                mImageView.setImageURI(filePath);
                Bitmap bmimage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);

                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmimage);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

But this is also not refreshing my image when coming back from the result of picking it into my gallery

What should I do ?

Hint

When I first strat my app, there is a default image set in that mImageView, then when I try to change it , the imageview is not updated, but this code works when I save and set the image again

thanks

Comment: setImageURI and setImageBitmap should do the same in the code you provided. Do you want to manually load the Bitmap for some later code, where this is only a code-snippet?
Have you tried [Glide](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/)?

Comment: yes, I have tried glide doing this /*Glide.with(this)         .load(new File(filePath.getPath())).into(mImageView);*/

Comment: but its not working at all, the code I posted only works when I load the first image, but not when doing it for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing this

```
Glide.with(context).load(imageURI).into(mImageView);
```